# Über das Verb "einfordern"

Tags: difference

> Man kann nicht Frieden und Ruhe **(ein)fordern**, wenn man seine Meditation nicht macht.
>   Der Vorgesetzte **forderte** Verbesserungen im Werbeanteil **(ein)**

Inwieweit werden die Bedeutungen der obigen Sätzen verändern, wenn man *fordern* durch *einfordern* ersetzt? Und was ist der Unterschied zwischen den beiden Verben?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**Einfordern** erscheint mir stärker/energischer und impliziert immer "von jemandem". Dieser "jemand" ist moralisch oder vertraglich dazu verpflichtet der Forderung nachzukommen. In deinem zweiten Beispiel wären dies die Angestellten, zu deren Aufgabe (per Arbeitsvertrag) es gehört für eine Verbesserung im Werbeanteil zu sorgen.

Wenn keine moralische oder vertragliche Pflicht vorliegt, würde ich nicht "einfordern" benutzen. Zum Beispiel: *Der Vorgesetzte forderte das Tragen von roten Pappnasen ein.*, klingt komisch mit dem "ein".

Entsprechend ist **fordern** allgemeiner und weniger bindend. Im Prinzip kann ich alles Mögliche *fordern* aber nur wenige Dinge *einfordern*.

Comment: Der letzte Satz ist der wichtige, denn *ein*fordern kann man nur, was ver*ein*bart wurde. Der Rest ist irrelevant oder, insbesondere der erste Absatz, unzutreffend.

Answer (score 8):

*Einfordern* kann man, was versprochen oder abgemacht ist (das schließt auch Dinge ein, die nach moralischen oder ethischen Grundsätzen selbstverständlich sind).

*Fordern* kann man das und alles andere.